# Connecting the elastic beanstalk environment with existing RDS instance

Tags: django, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an existing RDS MYSQL instance which is in default VPC. I want to connect to this instance through app running on Elastic beanstalk env, which i am not able to do. Beanstalk env and RDS instance are in same VPC and the security groups allow access to port 3306 for all the IPs. Can someone please help?

Opened all the security groups for accessing port 3306.

Below is settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpassword',
        'HOST': 'dbendpoint',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': { 'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your app load balanced? how are you attempting to connect to your RDS instance?

Comment: The app is not load balanced. I am connecting to the RDS instance through django app.

Comment: ok, can you connect to the rds instance manually, eg from a mysql client?

Comment: Yes, I am able connect to RDS instance from EC2 instance outside of Beanstalk and from my local machine, but not through EC2 instances in Beanstalk.

Comment: sounds like a problem with the app to me in that case, please post your `settings.py` and any other code that concerns connecting to the DB

Comment: Added db details as in settings.py, above.